# Angular - Binding checkboxes to ng-model from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some data coming back from a resource that looks like:

```
$scope.phones = [
    {
        Value: <some value>,
        IsDefault: true
    },
    {
        Value: <some value>
        IsDefault: false
    }
];
```

And for simplicity sake, here's the repeater:

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in phones">
    <input type="radio" name="phone" ng-model="phone.IsDefault" />
</div>
```

I would like whichever radio is checked to update the model accordingly - this is not happening. On page load, nothing is checked. I can use `ng-checked` - but without `ng-model` it wont bind back to the array. Am I missing something simple or am I stuck writing an `ng-change` event to manually update the array?

As of now, I wrote a `ng-change` event as well, it currently looks like:

```
ng-model="phone.IsDefault" ng-value="true" ng-change="newPhoneSelected($index)"

$scope.newPhoneSelected = function (index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.phones.length; i++) {
        if (i == index) $scope.phones[i].IsDefault = true;
        else $scope.phones[i].IsDefault = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ng-value... it is radio button they work based on the ng-value

Comment: Have tried using `ng-true-value="true"` and `ng-false-value="false"` - no luck - binding does not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing`ng-value`... it is radio button they work based on `value` to mark a value as selected. You need either `[value="" | ng-value=""]`

```
<input type="radio"
       ng-model=""
       [value="" |
       ng-value=""]>
```

Like:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-value="true" name="boolean" ng-model="myValue" /> True
 <input type="radio" ng-value="false" name="boolean"  ng-model="myValue" /> False
```

Here is a [plunker demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9t7e/)

Or with strings values:

```
$scope.myValue = 'Car'
```

**html**

```
 <input type="radio" ng-value="'Car'" name="string1" ng-model="myValue" /> Car
 <input type="radio" ng-value="'Airplane'" name="string1"  ng-model="myValue" /> Airplane
```

Here is the [second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YcC5F/)

This is probably the closest sample to what you  have:

http://jsfiddle.net/JbMuD/

Comment: `ng-false-value="false" ng-true-value="true" ng-model="phone.IsDefault"` - No change.

Comment: My radios are within a repeater tho - so setting one value to `false` isn't an option

Comment: @tymeJV you are missing the point  ng-model="myValue" let's say 'Car' only will mark selected the radio button with value="Car"

Answer (score 0):

A radio button is used to select one out of many values. You want to change the property of one item (`isDefault = true`) and simultaneously of another one (`isDefault = false`).

The semantically correct way would be to have some kind of `defaultPhone` value:

```
<div ng-repeat="phone in phones">
  <input type="radio" name="phone" ng-model="temp.defaultPhone" ng-value="phone"/>
</div>
```

Since your model requires that each phone "knows" itself wether it's default or not, you can add a listener:

```
$scope.$watch('temp.defaultPhone', function(defaultPhone) {
  $scope.phones.forEach(function(phone) {
    phone.isDefault = phone === defaultPhone;
  });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/U7kXoixvXzuDvMVqIQLt?p=preview).